# I need to output a numpy array to a column of an existing .xlsx file

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a list of lists that I have sliced using numpy and stored in the sliced_probabilities variable. I wish to save the output of this variable to column 'AU' of my 'Company_Data_Set.xlsx' file. I have tried to_excel, but that overwrites the entire the file. This array is a list of lists of dimension (3217, 1) so if reshaping is necessary I understand, but I desperately need help saving this output to column "AU" with a header of "P1 Probabilities". I've tried researching the topic independently without turning to stack but this is my last resort for now. Please assist in anyway you can please.

PS: I only displayed the most recent cell of the Juypter Notebook I am using numpy and pandas to to read the data frame, thank you for your time.

```
X = df2.drop(columns = ['ID', 'account type', 'Billing State/Province', 'Last Activity', 'ATS System', 
                        'Product O', 'Product MKT', 'Product PC', 'Product P1', 'Revenue Range', 'Industry', 'ofccp'])
y = df2['Product P1']
y_2 = df2['Product PC']
y_3 = df2['ofccp']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print(score)

probability_predictions = model.predict_proba(X)
print(probability_predictions)

sliced_probabilities = np.array(probability_predictions[0:, 0:1])
print(sliced_probabilities)

output:

0.7732919254658385
[[0.65325909 0.34674091]
 [0.71040741 0.28959259]
 [0.5        0.5       ]
 ...
 [0.53591285 0.46408715]
 [0.50274446 0.49725554]
 [0.5        0.5       ]]
[[0.65325909]
 [0.71040741]
 [0.5       ]
 ...
 [0.53591285]
 [0.50274446]
 [0.5       ]]
```

Comment: not sure I fully understand your question, are you trying to add a column? to_excel is for exporting your data into an excel file, and if it's the same filename as an existing file, it would override it. I would suggest to add a new column and set the sliced probabilities (check some examples here: https://towardsdatascience.com/4-methods-for-adding-columns-to-pandas-dataframes-dd0696863c16) then export in a different filename

Comment: Thank you, finally good documentation on why my specific situation wasn't allowing me to set a column with the df["header"] = list method: I needed to initialize my data frame as an actual data frame and not a read_excel dataframe, took over 6 hours to figure this out. Thank you so much.